# How does one access the Cisco Nexus 5000 terminal?

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus, cisco-nexus-7k

How does one access the Cisco Nexus 5000 terminal? There is a console port on the back and connecting directly to it does nothing; does it require a supervisor module or something?

Edit for clarity:

To be clear, I am using a Cisco certified DB-9 rollover cable, so the pinouts are correct (I have verified them).

My question is more along the lines of, "Does the Nexus 5596UP require something special to connect to the console port, such as a supervisor module or a magic wand?"

Comment: The console port is a serial port that requires a Cisco proprietary cable, a serial port on your host, and a terminal application configured to the same speed, parity, etc. that the console port is configured.

Comment: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5000/hw/installation/guide/nexus_5000_hig/connect.html

Comment: Thanks for answering guys, but I am aware of how db-9 rollover cable works.  Perhaps I should have been more specific; when I connect i connect a Cisco Certified rollover cable to my db-9 serial port on my PC, and then attempt to connect using the required 9600 8-n-1 settings, nothing happens. It is a blank screen. My questions was more along the lines of, "can the console port be disabled?"

Comment: You need to match the specific configuration of the serial interface, which may have been changed from the default. You may need to try different speed and other parameters.

Comment: That's actually a good idea Ron, but I have already cycled through them all. Is there any other way that the port may have been disabled?

Comment: No, there is some type of mismatch in your serial parameters, or you have something wrong with the serial interface or cable. I have also seen where, once you actually get the correct parameters, the terminal application may not work until reset. This is something a lot of people have trouble getting to work. Be sure to hold your tongue correctly as you try :)

Comment: Also (just to cover all bases), are you sure you are connected to the interface labeled CON, and not the MGMT, which is an ethernet interface?

Comment: Well thanks for all the good advice. Those were all sound ideas and suggestions, but I was hoping that maybe someone might be able to suggest something I hadn't tried already because you never know. I guess it's a brick.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may be a victim of this bug: [Nexus 5596: System fails to boot after a power cycle](https://bst.cloudapps.cisco.com/bugsearch/bug/CSCun66310)

**New question**: the bug notice indicates that there is a script that can be uploaded to the switch that will remediate the problem, but how can I upload the script if I can't get console access?

Answer (score -1):

You need a serial cable and eventually a USB adapter.
then after connecting the serial port on the back of your Cisco device and the USB to your pc, you will need to use a terminal program like putty and from it run a new serial connection.

Comment: USB is not a requirement. The requirement is a serial connection on your PC. Unfortunately, many laptops do not have a serial connections the way they used to, so you can use a USB to serial adapter, but, for example, I have a PC with a serial connection that I use to connect to my router, and it does not involve a USB connection.

Comment: Did you see the part about a "supervisor module"?

Comment: he is asking about connecting to a console port... what does it have to do with supervisor module?